# User goback history to homepage if previous page has not in my domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem when user click go back history.
I have a example code below:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()" class="back">Back History</a>
```

My user go direct to Page A from Google. Example: domain.com/page-a
. And user click goback history.I want user goback history to homepage if previous page is not in my domain.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: How you are making this anchor? You can add a check while making this anchor. Let's support if you are creating this anchor from JavaScript then you can use document.referrer to check the previous URL.

Comment: My skill of code is not good. Please help how to do like this.

Comment: JavaScript only works on pages on your domain, you cannot control where the Client navigates to once the are not on your site, without CORS access.

Answer (score 0):

Please understand back methods this methods working based on user navigation history .
user come from google or other site to your domain/ domain.com/page-a then when user click back button your page redirect to reference url only that is goto google or other site url .if you enter url direct blank tab in address bar then that time you click back button then redirect to blank page or go back to blank page.

The back() method loads the previous URL in the history list.

This is the same as clicking the "Back button" in your browser, or history.go(-1).

The history object contains the URLs visited by the user (within a browser window).

The history object is part of the window object and is accessed through the window.history property.

Comment: A website can do it on mobile. You can open a new tab on mobile and go to this link. And click to button sign: "<"    : https://tiki.vn/ao-hoodie-nam-seven-for-seven-zavans-p3604599.html?src=recently-viewed&2hi=0

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic example you can refer. It only works if you are adding the **LINK** in your webpage but if you are talking about to changing the browser back history button then it is not **POSSIBLE**.

```js
var referrerDomain = document.referrer.split('/')[2];
console.log(referrerDomain);
if (referrerDomain != "example.com") {
  var backHistory = document.getElementById("back-history");
  backHistory.href = "https://example.com";
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:history.back()" class="back" id="back-history">Back History</a>
```

I have added an `id` attribute in the HTML which is used in JavaScript. JavaScript is checking the referrer domain as shown in line no 3. Please change the `example.com` with your domain name and remove the `console.log()` once you verified the code.